# Laravel on Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS7.5 results in 500 Internal server error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to set up Laravel on IIS7.5 and I'm stuck for a while now.
I setted up the environment and the URL rewrite. When I place a common index.php with hello world in the public folder, the browser gives me "Hello World".
When I use the laravel index.php I get an 500 Internal Server Error.
Can anyone help me on this? I already tried 50 other solutions found on the internet but none of them really helped me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/public/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile"  ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />                     
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: seem to be error with your htaccess code. Can you see your application error log.

Comment: @SafoorSafdar , I thought that IIS uses the web.config file and not the .htaccess file?

Comment: Yeah exactly it is, it's another form of htaccess, but you can convert htaccess to web.config format using [Url Rewrite][1], but the main focus here to check your htaccess rule is valid as per laravel or not.

[1]:http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: #Problem with direct URLs on IIS servers
http://support.cms-guide.com/hc/en-us/articles/203591460-Problem-with-direct-URLs-on-IIS-servers
Hope it is helpful to you.

Comment: @SafoorSafdar I don't think the issue is related to my web.config I my opening post you can find my web.config, I already tried to change everything in my config file, also tried the url you sent me but it doesn't solve the issue